# It ran for eleven months in New York vs It has been running for eleven months in New York

Tags: grammar

In book Main Street by Lewis Sinclair stay the sentence:
"It ran for eleven months in New York."
Why Author didn't write:

It has been running for eleven months in New York

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't tell why the author made that choice. (It is possible that if you quoted more context it would be clearer; but it would not necessarily be.)

Both are fully grammatical and idiomatic.

The use of *ran* strongly suggests that it is not still running, and probably that it did not close recently, but longer ago.

The use of *has been running* would suggest that it is still running, or has only just closed.

By the way, your question is not grammatical:

> In **the** book Main Street by Lewis Sinclair **there is/appears** the sentence:

> Why **didn't the** Author write:

Answer (score 1):

"It ran" means it's over and has been over for a while, maybe. "It has been running" means it is still running. The word author is not capitalized in normal use.